# PageViewController and screen/data refresh

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm learning how to use a PageViewController and in the app I'm building I need to be able to refresh the content on the screen from the containing ViewController.

So in my storyboard I have:

a view controller, class `RoomPageListViewController`.

a view controller, class `RoomContentViewController` which has a number of labels which are update using CoreData.

a PageViewController

The setup is very simple, I can put in the entire code if needed but what I wanted to do is from `RoomPageListViewController` to be able to call a function within `RoomContentViewController` to update the labels and keep the user on the page that they are.

Whatever I tried has resulted in error, for example tried:

```
 let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RoomContentViewController") as! RoomContentViewController
 pageContentViewController.updateScreen()
```

But no luck... how can I accomplish this or am I doing it the 'wrong' way?

Thanks!

EDIT v3: With a protocol implementation now working fully!

This is the code for the RoomPageListViewController:

```
class RoomPageListViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

    var roomContentVCAccess: RoomContentVCAccess!

    var roomsList: Array<String> = ["Entire Home"]
    var roomButtonClicked: String = ""
    let activityInd: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
    var showInd: Bool = true
    let shadowLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height))
    var viewBySelection: Int = 1
    var roomDeviceGroupID: Int = 0
    var redrawBool: Bool = true
    var displayRoom: String = ""

    var pageViewController : UIPageViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.title = "Devices By Room"

        var backBtn : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: " ", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backBtn
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.enabled = false

        var settingsBtn : UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Settings", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goSettings")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingsBtn

        activityInd.stopAnimating()

        if showInd == true {
            startInd()
        }

    }


    func startInd() {
        shadowLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        shadowLabel.text = "Please Wait... Loading Data...\n\n\n\n\n"
        shadowLabel.numberOfLines = 6
        shadowLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        shadowLabel.center = CGPoint (x: screenSize.width/2 , y: screenSize.height/2)
        shadowLabel.alpha = 0.5
        shadowLabel.hidden = false

        activityInd.center = CGPoint (x: screenSize.width/2 , y: screenSize.height/2)
        activityInd.color = UIColor.blueColor()
        activityInd.startAnimating()
        activityInd.hidden = false

        self.view.addSubview( shadowLabel )
        self.view.addSubview( activityInd )

    }

    func stopInd() {
        shadowLabel.hidden = true
        activityInd.stopAnimating()
        activityInd.hidden = true

        showRooms()

        if (redrawBool == true) {
            //showRooms()
            reset()
        } else {
            self.roomContentVCAccess.updateScreen()
        }


        redrawBool = false
    }

    func showRooms() {
        roomsList = ["Entire Home"]

        var serverSettings:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = serverSettings.managedObjectContext!
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Devices")
        request.propertiesToFetch = NSArray(objects: "room") as [AnyObject]
        request.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.DictionaryResultType
        request.returnsDistinctResults = true
        let deviceFilter = NSPredicate (format: "room <> %@", "Unknown")
        request.predicate = deviceFilter

        var roomsResults: Array<AnyObject> = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

        println("count: \(roomsResults.count)")

        if roomsResults.count > 0 {


            for room in roomsResults {

                var theroom = room["room"] as! String

                if (theroom != "Alarm") {
                    roomsList.append(theroom)
                }

            }

        }

        println(roomsList)
    }

    func reset() {
        /* Getting the page View controller */
        pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as! UIPageViewController
        self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

        let pageContentViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
        self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([pageContentViewController!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

        self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height)
        self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
        self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
        self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        //stopInd()
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = (viewController as! RoomContentViewController).pageIndex!

        index++

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        var index = (viewController as! RoomContentViewController).pageIndex!

        if (index <= 0) {
            return nil
        }

        index--

        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)

    }

    func viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) -> UIViewController? {
        if ((self.roomsList.count == 0) || (index >= self.roomsList.count)) {
            return nil
        }

        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RoomContentViewController") as! RoomContentViewController

        self.roomContentVCAccess = pageContentViewController

        pageContentViewController.room = self.roomsList[index]
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

        displayRoom = self.roomsList[index]

        return pageContentViewController
    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

        return roomsList.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

        return 0
    }




}
```

and the code for RoomContentViewController:

```
 protocol RoomContentVCAccess {
     func updateScreen()
}

class RoomContentViewController: UIViewController, RoomContentVCAccess {

    var pageIndex: Int?
    var room : String!

    @IBOutlet weak var screenScrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        screenScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(screenScrollView.frame.size.width, 650)

        roomName.text = room

        btnViewAllRoomSensors.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        btnViewAllRoomSensors.layer.masksToBounds = true

        updateScreen()

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        updateScreen()
    }


    func updateScreen() {
        println(room)
        let roomValues = getLabelValues(room)
        println(roomValues)
        var roomDevicesCount: Array<Int> = roomValues[0] as! Array<Int>


        // more code here....

    }

    func getLabelValues(roomName: String) -> (Array<AnyObject>) {

        var serverSettings:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
        var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext = serverSettings.managedObjectContext!
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Devices")

        let deviceFilter = NSPredicate (format: "room = %@", roomName)

        // more CoreData code...

    }
```

The overall picture is that the app, once it receives data calls the stopInd() within RoomPageListViewController. From within stopInd() I need to be able to call updateScreen() that is in RoomContentViewController.

Comment: You could update your labels in `viewWillAppear` in your RoomContentViewController. So when your user will change to it, he will see the updated labels. I don't see why it is necessary to update them if the user doesn't see them

Comment: Thanks @FPWebSystems! I just want to update the labels on the screen & page they are viewing. How should I be able to do that?

Comment: Is the problem now solved? I understood your explanation: "to update the labels and keep the user on the page that they are" that you want to update the labels in `RoomContentViewController` while the user is in `RoomPageListViewController`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @FPWebSystems - I have added the code for the RoomPageListViewController. In my app, once some processing happens with data received from Sockets, the stopInd() is called. Once stopInd is called I need to refresh the page (and the labels) the user is seeing within the pageviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a protocol that the ViewController owning the labels conforms to. For example:

```
protocol RoomContentVCAccess
{
    func updateLabels()
}
```

Then in your RoomContentViewController's class declaration:

```
class RoomContentViewController: UIViewController, RoomContentVCAccess
{
    // ...

    // MARK: - RoomContentVCAccess
    func updateLabels()
    {
        // update your labels
    }
}
```

Your RoomPageListViewController also has to know who his roomContentVCAccess is. For that, just create an instance variable in RoomPageListViewController: `var roomContentVCAccess: RoomContentVCAccess!` and then say `self.roomContentVCAccess = viewController as! RoomContentViewController` in your `viewControllerAtIndex`-function.

And then when stopInd() is called in RoomPageListViewController, say `self.roomContentVCAccess.updateLabels()`.

Comment: I changed the code in the post to reflect the protocol. Now I get an error of: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when it tries to execute the self.roomContentVCAccess.updateScreen()

Comment: Something I'm doing wrong with the roomPageListVCReference.roomContentVCAccess = self, can you please elaborate on what I need to do there? Thx!

Comment: Can you provide the whole error text in the console?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: I try using a very simple function that just does println("test") to get it right... I think in my implementation I did something wrong. Can you check my code in the post it has been edited.

Comment: I put the declaration as: self.roomContentVCAccess = pageContentViewController within viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) and it seems to work now all the time! :)

Comment: Great! Please mark this answer as correct if it's now finally working. Thank you!